# issue with mplot3d example code: polys3d_demo.py

Tags: python, matplotlib

using the example code here

http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html

I get this error message
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ----
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
    last)
     in ()
        21     verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))
         22 
    ---> 23 poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=[cc('r'), cc('g'),

```
cc('b'),
     24                                          cc('y')])
     25 poly.set_alpha(0.7)

<ipython-input-2-f7e7e902fdd7> in cc(arg)
     11 
     12 def cc(arg):
---> 13     return mcolors.to_rgba(arg, alpha=0.6)
     14 
     15 xs = np.arange(0, 10, 0.4)

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.colors' has no attribute 'to_rgba'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the version of the example that matches the version of matplotlib in use.

E.g. if you are using matplotlib 1.5.3, you need to refer to the example for that version: http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html

This uses

```
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
# ...
colorConverter.to_rgba(arg, alpha=0.6)
```

to convert the color code to an RGBA color.